# Data sanitation in X-Editable possible?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm using the excellent [X-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) to enable inline editing of some data on my website. I now want to do some data sanitation (replace commas with dots) before the data gets submitted to the server. In the [X-editable docs](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) I can't find anything about this however.

Does anybody know how I can do some data checking and sanitation with X-Editable before data is saved? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `$(thing).editable({...})`](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable):

> Name: validate
>
> Type: function
>
> Default: null
>
> Description: Function for client-side validation. If returns string - means validation not passed and string showed as error. Since 1.5.1 you can modify submitted value by returning object from validate: {newValue: '...'} or {newValue: '...', msg: '...'}

```
validate: function(value) {
    if($.trim(value) == '') {
        return 'This field is required';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't seem to get returning the newValue to work. When I return an object with a newValue it simply doesn't update. It does reach that point and returns that object, but X-Editable doesn't continue with sending the value to the server. Would you know of or have a working example?

Comment: Excuse me, I was on version 1.5.0. It works great now!